# ListView Data from SimpleCursorAdapter result of a query

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, where-clause, simplecursoradapter

Since a few month I am engaged with Android development and now I have a problem I dont get the right answer.

I have a ListView with data filled from a SimpleCursorAdapter. The query which should provides the results has a where statement, but it returns all records of the table.

```
final Cursor c = mStorage.loadList();
startManagingCursor(c);
c.moveToFirst();
final ListCursorAdapter adapter = 
new ListCursorAdapterAusgabe(this, R.layout.listview,
c, FROM, TO);
adapter.setViewBinder(new ListViewBinderAusgabe());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The query:

```
int mode = 0;
public Cursor loadList() {
return mDb.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE.NAME, TABLE.ALL_COLUMNS, 
"mode=?", new String [] {String.valueOf(mode)}, null, null, null, null);
}
```

In read in this forum that there must be an _id column: In the above mentioned table there is one column with "_id". I also tried to enter "mode" in single quotations and double quotations but it didn't work. Has anybody an idea?

Thank you in advance,

Hadja

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
return mDb.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE.NAME, TABLE.ALL_COLUMNS, 
    "mode=" + String.valueOf(mode), null, null, null, null, null);
```

?

Comment: Franziskus Thanks for your answers! Yes I have tried, but it also shows all records!